# change or disable default json serialization on an asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, json.net, pagemethods

how to prevent default serialization in a aspnet webform web method (not api or mvc) in order to user Json.net

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[WebMethod]
public static object MyMethod()
{
     dynamic field1 = new JObject();
     field1.Alessio = "ciao"; 

     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(field1);        
}
```

the output is:

```
{"d":"{\"Alessio\":\"ciao\"}"}
```

instead it should be

```
{"d":"{ "Alessio ": "ciao"}"}
```

because the serialization has been applied twice (from JsonConvert.SerializeObject and from the default serializer)

is there a way to:
- disable the default serialization for a single webmethod?
or
- change the default serializer with Json.Net serializar only on a page or on a method?
or
- change the default serializer with Json.Net globally?

The project is a webform application (not an api or a mvc application) and is not intended to move WebMethods on a WCF or on a HttpHandler

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON.  Did you mean `{"d": { "Alessio": "ciao" } }` instead?

Answer (score 4):

I made the webmethod "`void`" (in order to prevent automatic serialization)
and set the correct http headers by hand/manually craft the Response:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod()
{
    .....
    ...
    ..
    string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_d);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", result.Length.ToString());                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(result);
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Comment: That's the only way to override the default serializer for page and asmx methods that I know of.